# Does Data Synchronization between servers count as distributed system?

Tags: database, distributed, distributed-computing, data-synchronization, distributed-system

I'm just a little bit confused of this concept.

I heard the words "Distributed system" a lot, but I'm not really sure my stuff is kind of "Distributed system".

Basically,  we have a master server( a very big one) as the front line production server.

Then , in order to reduce the load of master server(no crush it by ton of tasks). We put all kind of jobs into different small servers.

These small server consummate with master server pull & push processed data between each other.

But once I heard "Distributed System" i really get frightened, it feels so big for me , I don't really know my job is related or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your small description it sounds like you have a bonafide distributed system.

From our good friend wikipedia:

`A distributed system is a software system in which components located on networked computers communicate and coordinate their actions by passing messages.[1] The components interact with each other in order to achieve a common goal. Three significant characteristics of distributed systems are: concurrency of components, lack of a global clock, and independent failure of components.[1] Examples of distributed systems vary from SOA-based systems to massively multiplayer online games to peer-to-peer applications.`

I think you fit the description because:

1)  A common goal is being done by different servers.
2)  The servers are communicating with each other by passing messages.

That second one is pretty important for multiple reasons.  Besides the benefits you get from having these servers communicating with each other, it also means that as an engineer you are tackling the traditional problems that people in the distributed systems field handle. It exposes you to these problems and while you might not feel like you are in the field or you might not use the same jargon, you will be presented with the same problems and solutions.